# I am a approver and didnt receive email after someone publish a new page, why?

Tags: 2013, approval-process

I am using sharepoint 2013. We have enabled the publish approval workflow. When a enduser with contributor rights add a new page, he save it, check it in and click on the button publish.

I am a user in the usergroup "approvers". I espect an email with the information about this new item and some hyperlink to this item. When I click on this hyperlink I can approve or decline.

I dont receive an email. Is there someone know why? I need now go to the list and look at the column "approvalstatus".

Here are my settings:

[image]

UPDATE:
I dont have a explicit enabled some workflow. Is this my problem? I was thinking the publis approval workflow is enabled automaticly by the settings in the first picture (version settings of my list).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the settings of the publishing approval workflow. Approvers, by default, are just people with approval privileges. To have them notified by the workflow, you need to add them to the approvers field in the association form:

[image: Association Form for Approval Workflow]

The association form is shown when you attach the workflow to a list. You can access it from list settings > workflow settings > your workflow > edit (?)

EDIT:

In your list settings, nothing indicates an approval workflow is running. You need to add it manually.

What do you have configured ?

- Content Approval

  - This means Approval is necessary to publish an item. It does not indicate any workflow is running, although a publishing approval workflow will integrate with this and start automatically when approval is requested.
- Versioning - Minor versions

  - Draft versions are necessary for Approval workflow
- Checkout is required

  - Unrelated to Content Approval
  - Just means you are forced to checkout a document before making edits, meaning noone else can make edits in the meantime.

EDIT 2:

A quick google returned [this tutorial](http://blog.incworx.com/blog/who-is-the-best-chicago-sharepoint-firm/creating-an-approval-workflow-for-sharepoint-2013).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Please see my update in my post.

Comment: ahhhh ok ok..isnt there some tutorial how you enable the publish approval workflow? I would like to avoid some step.

Comment: what about your explanation of the option in the version settings "Content Approval". This is enabled in my situation. And I see the publish button. This is not enouvh to start the publish approval workflow?

Comment: Correct, these are 2 seperate things. One is "simple" content approval, managed by the users. No workflow tasks or emails are created. When you add an approval workflow, users will get tasks assigned and will have to approve these tasks instead of the items directly.

Comment: Damn you are so good. My last question. In the tutorial I see "Approval - Sharepoint 2010". In my situation I see this workflow also, but I see also "Publish approval" workflow. What is the differance?

Comment: Now you've got me :). I have no idea, I was wondering this myself recently and all I could come up with is that they're added by different features and maybe they are from a different SP Version. So far, I haven't dug deep enough to see a difference.

Comment: Ok ok..no problem. I was just wondering. So the publish option without workflow is not triggering the approvers. No task, no email. Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

Is the workflow service enabled on your site? Do you get mails for other events including publishing? Check your site settings > associated workflows.

Comment: I dont see some link "associated workflows" in my site settings.